Do large companies like Facebook, Google, Netflix, etc., have internal documentation for their frontend and backend codebases?
I work at a fairly large startup/company of about 1000 people, a fraction of which are software engineers. We have some docs of various kinds, but the codebase isn't documented. Let me elaborate.
Here is what we do have.

"Getting started with the codebase" guides (how to configure your new machine to run the code).
External product walkthroughs (from a UI perspective, usually on the marketing site)
Internal product roadmaps, notes, bug lists, todo lists, etc..
Slack with lots of communication about code, product, etc..
Storybook documentation of central reusable UI library (includes standard UI library components like tooltips, modals, etc., not product-specific stuff).
Unit tests, integration tests.

But what we don't have is:

Documentation of the frontend codebase. We use TypeScript, so we have types, but they are not explained how they are used or what the various props mean, etc.. We have lots of modules of various types, but few if any code comments, except when things get particularly harry, complicated, or hacky and you need comments to explain wth is happening. So it's hard to tell how to use what we have, let alone know what is even in the codebase, unless you read though the 10's of thousands of modules/files in the codebase, which is impractical.
Documentation of the backend codebase. Same situation here, but an even larger codebase.
Documentation of the overall architecture of the company software products as a whole (so you can see how things are wired together). Stuff like devops, infra, etc... Subteams might have docs they put together for this or that, but there is not much in terms of cross-team global shared docs on all this stuff.

So I'm wondering what the practices are of large companies with lots of resources (Facebook, Google, Netflix, etc.), or even smaller companies but still considered a fairly decent size). How much codebase documentation do they have? When do they get around to creating it?
Some code is probably used by several subdivisions of the company (i.e. "central" code), so this likely won't change every day. But other code is used by the "lef nodes" of the company, such as new products or divisions of the company, so might change and evolve rapidly. So I'd expect there to at least be documentation for the central code, but maybe not much for the leaf code.
For the central code, what I'd find most useful as a new employee is a high-level overview of what the main modules are, and how you might use them, with a few examples of usage. This would let me know what I don't need to recreate, as well as what's possible in the codebase.
Then as a second layer, it might be nice to have some rough API-level documentation on the frontend/backend, to show you examples of how you might write specific code. But I wouldn't expect every single function and it's interface to be well described and documented like you find in a popular open source project.
But what is it like in a bigger company? Please elaborate a little on what you have seen, so I can get a sense of what would be realistic to implement wherever others may work, when there is little code documentation when they start.

This varies by company and product. There is not a general answer.

If you have a document that tells me how to get from a brand new computer fresh out of a box to a machine where I can build and debug the software, make changes and put them into the review process, and that documentation works, I’m happy.

In my experience developers never want to write documentation. It's managers that want developers to write documentation.
They want documentation for various reasons

To present at meetings with other teams
So they can look stuff other teams have done
So they can see what an old project did
To show to new employees
To manage projects
To meet rules that have been setup in the past

Generally speaking the larger the company the more managers there are, the more teams there are and the more projects there are. This drives the creation of more and more documentation.
Now there is a whole argument you could get into about whether this documentation is needed or even good. But we can all* agree on the following

There is an amount of documentation which is too much
There is an amount of documentation which is too little

If you work at a small company you might find there isn't enough documentation. especially if someone leaves.
If you work at a large company you may well find there is too much documentation, you can't find the bit you want and a lot of time is used writing it.
At large companies more thought goes into what documentation should be written. Projects are longer and will have whole sets of forms to be filled in and signed off to start and stop them. Reviews will be taken place on old projects and again documented. Various standards for what should be written will be themselves documented and the adherence to them will also be documented and audited.
Let's look at a case study.
George is a senior manager at Global Software Ltd. This year he has been tasked with a high level goal "Increase sales in new markets by 20%" In order to make this happen he first organises a meeting the other senior managers. This may be at an off site location with a good selection of canapes. Together with a management consultant they write, sorry "produce" a document which lists this goal along with some others for each manager. They call it "The Big Plan"
George returns to the office the next day* and calls in his subordinate manager Jane. "Jane, we have a very important document here, we need to achieve point 4 by the end of the year! I'll leave it in your hands"
Jane immediately organises a meeting with the other managers. They get together in one of the nicer offices with the good biscuits and some fizzy water from the fridge. "Guys! point 4 is very important, we need to come up with some ideas to do this" They work very hard and write 5 more documents outlining various projects they think might improve sales. Jane gives project X to her subordinate Bob. "I need time lines on this STAT!"
Bob salutes and hurrys off to see if project X makes any sense and how long it will take how much t will cost etc. He assembles a team of senior technical people to argue about it.
The team meet up in a meeting room that was booked for something else, but the people didn't turn up. There are some sandwiches left over from something. The cooler architects and contractors have take away coffees. They open up their Microsoft surface pros and start discussing what the hell project X is and how to make it work. The team is highly motivated and super productive top 1% tech people. They quickly produce several documents with diagrams and colours headings some use something called UML, which needs its own sub documentation to explain the arrows.
Consulting the documentation they already have about "How to start projects" They also write down everything that happened in the meeting and make a sharepoint page. They reference point 4 on the Big Plan, Bob, Jane and George. They link to all their own documents and make a whole bunch of sign off forms for money and time from teams
Bob then presents this all to Jane, Jane amends and signs and goes back and forth, she takes Project X along with the 5 other projects to her meeting in the nice room again where all the plans are discussed, updated, queried, signed etc
This generates a lot of requests for more information, changes to the plan to make it cheaper or add more things. each documented and double signed off.
Eventually a signed off plan with a whole bunch of diagrams and notes will make it to one or more development teams. They will meet, sort of, in the office but they will skype from their desks. Some will have snacks. If they are lucky the plan will basically match what they have already written and not require too much documentation on how it differs to be written.
Everyone gets champagne! The purchase will be documented.
Obviously i have skipped some of the facts and figures here for brevity but on average the number of pages of documentation varies in a bell curve with the quality of snacks at each meeting.

*not really
*quarter

In my experience developers never want to write documentation, but they still want documentation to exist. Only a small subset are keen enough to open up the source of some library they want to use, just to find out how to call it  .

@mattfreake As soon as you have virtual functions the source code doesn’t help anymore, because it might not even exist until you write it.

hmm that's all well and good, but do you have a graph?

Also, I'm not really saying documentation is bad, or not needed. the question is what documentation is like at big companies. For every well written man page, or helpfull arch diagram stats show there will be 373.12 pages of meeting notes and project plans
